# Flutter: How can I add onPressed commands when I use card widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, clickable

I want to direct people who touch the card to a different page.
I can't use onPressed commands. For eg. when I tap the "to do card", i want to navigate different page.

```
               SizedBox(
                  width:160.0,
                  height: 150.0,
                  child: Card(

                    color: Color.fromARGB(255,21, 21,21),
                    elevation: 2.0,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
                    ),
                    child:Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image.asset("assets/images/todo.png",width: 64.0,),
                          
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10.0,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Todo List",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20.0
                            ),
                          ),
                        
                        ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the GestureDetector is to use an InkWell if you want some splash effect where you pressed.

Something like this:

```
              SizedBox(
                width: 160.0,
                height: 150.0,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/secondPage'),
                  child: Card(
                      //
                      // All your card information
                      //
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your card with a gesture detector and do the navigation in its onTap method like this

```
child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/secondPage')
        },
        child: Card(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255,21, 21,21),
                    elevation: 2.0,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
                    ),
                    child:Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image.asset("assets/images/todo.png",width: 64.0,),
                          
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10.0,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Todo List",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20.0
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                       ),
                      )
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem fixed when I use "GestureDetector" or "Inkwell". Here is an answer.

```
               SizedBox(
                  width:160.0,
                  height: 150.0,
                  
                  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Start()));
    },
                  
                  child: Card(

                    color: Color.fromARGB(255,21, 21, 21),
                    elevation: 2.0,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
                    ),
                    child:Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Image.asset("assets/images/note.png",width: 64.0,),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10.0,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Notes",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 20.0
                                ),
                              ),
                              
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                    ),
                  ),),
                ),
```